# Cleaner way to export names

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

When I export my group data from exchange/AD I am left with the full domain name, including CN=, OU=, OU=, ect. Is there something I can change in my script to get it to export just the name, instead of having to go into excel and search and replace what I dont want?

```
#Written by Tekwhat 10-26-17
write-host "Group Memberships"
#Settings for file ouput
$fLocation = "D:\Exchange Reports\O365 Reports\"

import-module activedirectory

#Get OU
$OU = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the OU name to search: (0202 - Dev Bank)"

#create File to write report to:
$fName = $fLocation+$OU+" Group Memberships.csv"
$test = test-path $fName
    if ($test -eq $True)
        {
            write-host "Removing Old File..." -ForeGroundColor Red
            Remove-Item $fName
        }
    #Else
        #{
            #New-Item $fName -type file
        #}
Write-host "Creating New File..." -ForeGroundColor darkgreen
New-Item $fName -type file


$SearchBase = "OU=$OU,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domain,DC=local"
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | % { [ADSI]("LDAP://$_") }
 
$Members = @()
 
foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups){
              $Members += $ADGroup.Member |
                           Select -Property @{Name="ADGroup";Expression={$ADGroup.cn}},
                           @{Name="Member";Expression={$_}}
}
 

$Members | Select-Object AdGroup, Member | Export-Csv -Path $fname -NoType
write-host "Your file is located at " $fname -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```

The export of above gives something like this:

> "All Employees","CN=Test X User,OU=OUname,OU=Hosted Exchange
>   Customers,DC=Domain,DC=local"

Which I have to go into excel and search replace "CN=" and "OU=OUname,OU=Hosted Exchange
Customers,DC=Domain,DC=local" to have usable data.

Comment: i believe that `CN=*` stuff is called a `distinguished name`. if that is correct, then you can use something like `Get-ADUser -Identity $DN_To_Check` to get the use name/display-name as needed.

Comment: There are so many good scripts for this to be found.. Anyway, @Lee_Daily is correct about it being a DistinghuishedName. Don't try to regex your way through that, but use it as Identity parameter for the `Get-ADObject` cmdlet. That way you can determine if the member is a user or another group by looking at the returned object's `ObjectClass` property. See [Get-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adobject?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I am assuming incorrectly, but I believe you are having trouble with the output of the member property. You may use something like the following:

```
$SearchBase = "OU=$OU,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domain,DC=local"
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties Member,CN

$Members = @()
foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups){
    $Members += $ADGroup.Member |
        Select -Property @{Name="ADGroup";Expression={$ADGroup.cn}},
        @{Name="Member";Expression={($_ | Select-String -pattern "(?<=CN=).*?(?=,OU=|,DC=)").matches.value}}
}
```

One potential effect of the code above is that you will have an duplicate ADGroup names for each member. If that is not intended, then things will need to be changed.

I maintained a majority of your code, so I will explain what I changed:

`($_ | Select-String -pattern "(?<=CN=).*?(?=,OU=|,DC=)").matches.value`

- `$_` refers to the current pipeline object from `$ADGroup.Member`
- `Select-String` selects a string from the pipeline input based on a regex match in this case. The regex text is passed to the `-pattern` parameter.
- `"(?<=CN=).*?(?=,OU=|,DC=)"` is the regex (regular expression).

  - `(?<=CN=)`: `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind mechanism that looks for the string `CN=` behind the current position in the match.
  - `.*?` matches as few as possible characters (`.`) except newline characters
  - `(?=,OU=|,DC=)` uses the positive lookahead mechanism (`(?=)`) to find string `,OU=` or (`|`) the string `,DC=`.
- `.Matches` is the `Matches` property of the `Select-String` output. It contains other properties that are useful for specifying regex capture groups or select from multiple matches. One such property is `value`, which contains the actual string match.
- The lookahead and lookbehind mechanisms do not capture any matches. They are merely positional to control where you are in the match sequence.

Comment: It does seem to be the member output, its spitting out the cn and stuff. I wonder if I tell it instead to pull the exchange name, instead of AD member, it might just spit out the name?

In your example, does the cn and ou/dc inside ( ) make it not ouput it?

Comment: I am outputting everything between CN= and ,OU. For example, `CN=Group Name,OU=OrgUnit,DC=domain` would output `Group Name`. Is that what you are going for? I can add explanation if this output is your desired output.

Comment: That is indeed the desired output. If its not too much trouble can you give a brief explanation of what that's doing? I am still a powershell, well programming for that matter, baby.

Comment: I added some explanation. I hope this helps and let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for that, I attempted to add the code to my script, but now it doesn't output anything for the member.

Comment: What were the contents of `$ADGroups` just before this code block runs? I also don't understand why you have `% { [ADSI]("LDAP://$_") }` because `get-adgroup -filter * -properties member,cn` will capture everything you need. It does appear unnecessary or I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are over engineering this, based on your end goal. Correct me if I am wrong. Yet, in looking at your code, and your end goal, this would be my take on it.

No need for Write-Host (except for the color stuff) just to send to the screen (Write-Output) is the default, so you don't specifically have to write that out either, but that's a style choice.

```
"Create OU based Group Memberships Report"

$fLocation = 'C:\Temp'

# no need to do this as modules are auto imported since v3, but it does not hurt to have it here
# Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

# Use a GUI to provide an OU list to select from.
$OUName = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, DistinguishedName | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Select the OU name to search' -PassThru

# Set a file name to use. 'spaces in files names are just bad', so remove them
$fName = "$(($OUName).Name)_OU_ADGroup_Membership.csv" -replace ' '

# Remove any report of the same name
If(Test-Path -Path "$fLocation\$fName")
{ 
    Write-Warning -Message "A previous version of the report file is in the destination folder. Removing the file!"
    Remove-Item -Path "$fLocation\$fName" -Force
}

# Collect OU, AD group and user data and create a new CSV file
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $OUName.DistinguishedName | 
ForEach{
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $PSItem | 
    ForEach{
        $ADGroup = $PSItem.Name
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'GroupName';Expression = {$ADGroup}}, 
        Name, SamAccountName | 
        Export-Csv -Path "$fLocation\$fName" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}

Write-Host "Your new report file is licated here: $fLocation\$fName" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Import-Csv -Path "$fLocation\$fName"

#Results

WARNING: A previous version of the report file is in the destination folder. Removing the file!
Your new report file is licated here: C:\Temp\LabUsers_OU_ADGroup_Membership.csv

GroupName                   Name                  SamAccountName
---------                   ----                  --------------
...                                                  
TestUsers                   Test User001          testuser001
...
```

Comment: I attempted to run this, and it comes back with "group.name is not found in DC=domain, OU=local" I tried changing it to -SeachBase 'SubOuHere' which gives me the drilled down list to select from, but im not sure why its throwing the above error with and without the -SearchBase added.